# STM32 CMSIS FreeRTOS: configASSERT triggered when releasing BinrarySemaphore from ISR

Tags: arm, stm32, freertos, cmsis

I have a UART Idle interrupt that is supposed to notify a task that activity on the UART has ended.

For this I am using a BinarySemaphore which in this case is just a Semaphore with max count of 1.

When I call the semaphore release function `osSemaphoreRelease(semaphore_id_uart4_rx);`

The application halts due to the following assert being triggered.

```
/* Normally a mutex would not be given from an interrupt, especially if
    there is a mutex holder, as priority inheritance makes no sense for an
    interrupts, only tasks. */
    configASSERT( !( ( pxQueue->uxQueueType == queueQUEUE_IS_MUTEX ) && ( pxQueue->pxMutexHolder != NULL ) ) );
```

The macro `configASSERT` expands to

```
if ((!( ( pxQueue->pcHead == ((void *)0) ) && ( pxQueue->pcTail != ((void *)0) ) )) == 0) {vPortRaiseBASEPRI(); for( ;; );}
```

Now pxQueue->pcHead has a value of 0 and pxQueue->pcTail has a non 0 value. So the asseert is getting triggered.

The comment above this assert indicates that this is meant to catch use of MUTEXes from ISR. However, I am not using a MUTEX, I am using a BinarySemaphore ! FreeRTOS FAQ itself encourages you to use Semaphores or BinarySemaphores for syncronization between ISR and Task. Which is what I am doing. But still a Binary Semaphore is getting detected as a MUTEX which causes this problem. I even tried disabling MUTEXes from STM32CubeMX RTOS config, but it still detects it as a MUTEX and crashes.

[Binary semaphores for FreeRTOS real time embedded software applications](https://www.freertos.org/Embedded-RTOS-Binary-Semaphores.html)

> Binary semaphores and mutexes are very similar but have some subtle
>   differences: Mutexes include a priority inheritance mechanism, binary
>   semaphores do not. This makes binary semaphores the better choice for
>   implementing synchronisation (between tasks or between tasks and an
>   interrupt), and mutexes the better choice for implementing simple
>   mutual exclusion.

I am using NUCLEO-F429ZI board which has STM32F429ZIT6 on it, 
CubeMX version: 4.27.0, 
Firmware Package Name & Version: STM32Cube FW_F4 V1.21.0

Code:

Main Function:

```
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

    for(int i=0;i<360;i++) {
        sine_wave_array[i]=sin(i/180.0 * 3.1416)*1900 + 1900 + 100;

        if(sine_wave_array[i]<0) {
            sine_wave_array[i]=0;
        } else if(sine_wave_array[i]>=4096){
            sine_wave_array[i]=4095;
        }
    }

    //Initialize HMI struct
    memset(&hmi,0,sizeof(hmi));


  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_UART4_Init();
  MX_UART5_Init();
  MX_DAC_Init();
  MX_TIM6_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_ADC3_Init();
  MX_USB_OTG_HS_PCD_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  MX_SPI4_Init();
  MX_I2C2_Init();
  MX_CAN1_Init();
  MX_RTC_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  MX_TIM4_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */




    HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc3,adcData,ADC_CHANNEL_COUNT);
    __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart4, UART_IT_IDLE);

    // Setting IRQ priority for UART4
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(UART4_IRQn, 15, 15);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping(0);


  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_MUTEX */
  /* add mutexes, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_MUTEX */


  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_SEMAPHORES */
  /* add semaphores, ... */
  semaphore_id_uart4_rx = osSemaphoreCreate(osSemaphore(semaphore_uart4_rx), 1);
  semaphore_id_uart5_rx = osSemaphoreCreate(osSemaphore(semaphore_uart5_rx), 1);
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_SEMAPHORES */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_TIMERS */
  /* start timers, add new ones, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_TIMERS */

  /* Create the thread(s) */
  /* definition and creation of defaultTask */
  osThreadDef(defaultTask, StartDefaultTask, osPriorityNormal, 0, 128);
  defaultTaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(defaultTask), NULL);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_THREADS */
  /* add threads, ... */
  osThreadDef(LWIPTask_, LWIPTask, osPriorityNormal, 0, 1024);
  LWIPTaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(LWIPTask_), NULL);

  osThreadDef(USBTask_, USBTask, osPriorityNormal, 0, 512);
  USBTaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(USBTask_), NULL);


  /* USER CODE END RTOS_THREADS */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_QUEUES */
  /* add queues, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_QUEUES */


  /* Start scheduler */
  osKernelStart();

  /* We should never get here as control is now taken by the scheduler */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}
```

ISR:

```
void HAL_UART_IRQHandler(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
   uint32_t isrflags   = READ_REG(huart->Instance->SR);
   uint32_t cr1its     = READ_REG(huart->Instance->CR1);
   uint32_t cr3its     = READ_REG(huart->Instance->CR3);
   uint32_t errorflags = 0x00U;
   uint32_t dmarequest = 0x00U;

   if ((isrflags & USART_SR_IDLE) != RESET) {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        volatile uint32_t tmp; /* Must be volatile to prevent optimizations */
        tmp = huart->Instance->SR; /* Read status register */
        tmp = huart->Instance->DR; /* Read data register */
        HAL_UART_IdleCallback(huart);
    }

  /* If no error occurs */
  errorflags = (isrflags & (uint32_t)(USART_SR_PE | USART_SR_FE | USART_SR_ORE | USART_SR_NE));
  if(errorflags == RESET)
  {
    /* UART in mode Receiver -------------------------------------------------*/
    if(((isrflags & USART_SR_RXNE) != RESET) && ((cr1its & USART_CR1_RXNEIE) != RESET))
    {
      UART_Receive_IT(huart);
      return;
    }
  }  

  /* If some errors occur */
  if((errorflags != RESET) && (((cr3its & USART_CR3_EIE) != RESET) || ((cr1its & (USART_CR1_RXNEIE | USART_CR1_PEIE)) != RESET)))
  {
    /* UART parity error interrupt occurred ----------------------------------*/
    if(((isrflags & USART_SR_PE) != RESET) && ((cr1its & USART_CR1_PEIE) != RESET))
    {
      huart->ErrorCode |= HAL_UART_ERROR_PE;
    }

    /* UART noise error interrupt occurred -----------------------------------*/
    if(((isrflags & USART_SR_NE) != RESET) && ((cr3its & USART_CR3_EIE) != RESET))
    {
      huart->ErrorCode |= HAL_UART_ERROR_NE;
    }

    /* UART frame error interrupt occurred -----------------------------------*/
    if(((isrflags & USART_SR_FE) != RESET) && ((cr3its & USART_CR3_EIE) != RESET))
    {
      huart->ErrorCode |= HAL_UART_ERROR_FE;
    }

    /* UART Over-Run interrupt occurred --------------------------------------*/
    if(((isrflags & USART_SR_ORE) != RESET) && ((cr3its & USART_CR3_EIE) != RESET))
    { 
      huart->ErrorCode |= HAL_UART_ERROR_ORE;
    }

    /* Call UART Error Call back function if need be --------------------------*/    
    if(huart->ErrorCode != HAL_UART_ERROR_NONE)
    {
      /* UART in mode Receiver -----------------------------------------------*/
      if(((isrflags & USART_SR_RXNE) != RESET) && ((cr1its & USART_CR1_RXNEIE) != RESET))
      {
        UART_Receive_IT(huart);
      }

      /* If Overrun error occurs, or if any error occurs in DMA mode reception,
         consider error as blocking */
      dmarequest = HAL_IS_BIT_SET(huart->Instance->CR3, USART_CR3_DMAR);
      if(((huart->ErrorCode & HAL_UART_ERROR_ORE) != RESET) || dmarequest)
      {
        /* Blocking error : transfer is aborted
           Set the UART state ready to be able to start again the process,
           Disable Rx Interrupts, and disable Rx DMA request, if ongoing */
        UART_EndRxTransfer(huart);

        /* Disable the UART DMA Rx request if enabled */
        if(HAL_IS_BIT_SET(huart->Instance->CR3, USART_CR3_DMAR))
        {
          CLEAR_BIT(huart->Instance->CR3, USART_CR3_DMAR);

          /* Abort the UART DMA Rx channel */
          if(huart->hdmarx != NULL)
          {
            /* Set the UART DMA Abort callback : 
               will lead to call HAL_UART_ErrorCallback() at end of DMA abort procedure */
            huart->hdmarx->XferAbortCallback = UART_DMAAbortOnError;
            if(HAL_DMA_Abort_IT(huart->hdmarx) != HAL_OK)
            {
              /* Call Directly XferAbortCallback function in case of error */
              huart->hdmarx->XferAbortCallback(huart->hdmarx);
            }
          }
          else
          {
            /* Call user error callback */
            HAL_UART_ErrorCallback(huart);
          }
        }
        else
        {
          /* Call user error callback */
          HAL_UART_ErrorCallback(huart);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        /* Non Blocking error : transfer could go on. 
           Error is notified to user through user error callback */
        HAL_UART_ErrorCallback(huart);
        huart->ErrorCode = HAL_UART_ERROR_NONE;
      }
    }
    return;
  } /* End if some error occurs */

  /* UART in mode Transmitter ------------------------------------------------*/
  if(((isrflags & USART_SR_TXE) != RESET) && ((cr1its & USART_CR1_TXEIE) != RESET))
  {
    UART_Transmit_IT(huart);
    return;
  }

  /* UART in mode Transmitter end --------------------------------------------*/
  if(((isrflags & USART_SR_TC) != RESET) && ((cr1its & USART_CR1_TCIE) != RESET))
  {
    UART_EndTransmit_IT(huart);
    return;
  }
}
```

Functions called from ISR:

```
void HAL_UART_IdleCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart) {
    HAL_UART_RxGenericCallback(huart,3);
}

void HAL_UART_RxGenericCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart,int type) {

    if(type ==3) {

        if(UART4 == huart->Instance) {
            end4 = huart->RxXferSize - __HAL_DMA_GET_COUNTER(huart->hdmarx);
            osSemaphoreRelease(semaphore_id_uart4_rx);
        } else if (UART5 == huart->Instance) {
            end5 = huart->RxXferSize - __HAL_DMA_GET_COUNTER(huart->hdmarx);
            osSemaphoreRelease(semaphore_id_uart5_rx);
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you create this semaphore? And in general it would be better if you provide Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example.

Comment: show **your** code not the RTOS one. We know the RTOS one and the error is not there only in **your code**

Comment: Added code snippets

Answer (score 0):

in interrupts you need to use `..FromISR` functions or macros for example

`xSemaphoreTakeFromISR()`, `xSemaphoreGiveFromISR()` etc etc

You need also to set the correct interrupt priorities otherwise you will stack in constant stalls and HFs.

Comment: xSemaphoreTakeFromISR(), xSemaphoreGiveFromISR() etc are FreeRTOS functioins. I am using the CMSIS wrapper which in turn correctly calls these FreeRTOS functions.

Comment: For the interrupt priority, this is what I am using:  // Setting IRQ priority for UART4
 HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(UART4_IRQn, 15, 15);
 HAL_NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping(0);

Comment: In the call stack, I can see that the FromISR() fucntions are being called.

Comment: i would advice - do not use this CMSIS "extensions". Stick to the freeRTOS API.